# android Refresh UI from background

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have three tabs(Activity1, Activity2, Activity3) in tab_Activity, i want to update  Activity1 UI from Activity3 when certain event is Raised in Activity3  Can any one help me please,is Handler() works for it ? suggest me any code 0r link i am new to Android i know how to do it in Iphone...thx in Advance

Comment: no need to make it all bold...

Answer (score 2):

You should probably not update the UI elements of one Activity from another, because you can't guarantee that the hidden Activity has been initialized or hasn't been cleaned up.  The way to go about this is to create "model" objects that represent the state of your application.  In onCreate of Activity1, you initialize your UI elements - make member variables that refer to your UI elements, and initialize them with findViewById.  When an Activity is being shown, the onResume method is called.  Refresh your UI elements from the model at this point.  onResume is guaranteed to be executed after onCreate, so at this point you are guaranteed to have references to your UI elements.